# Получить массив нужного вида

Tags: php

module

```
 if(!empty($_POST['selected'])) {// тут приходят нужные id

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['selected']); $i++) {
            $order_id = $_POST['selected'][$i];
            $orders = $this->db->query("SELECT telephone, ttn FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'")->rows;

            $result = array();
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $result['ttn'][] = $order['ttn'];
                $result['phone'][] = $order['telephone'];
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
```

получаю массив

```
 Array
    (
        [ttn] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21256565225656363
        )

        [phone] => Array
    (
        [0] => +380956173282
    )

    )       
    Array
    (
        [ttn] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456554654645356555
        )

        [phone] => Array
            (
                [0] => +380956173282
            )

    )
```

подскажите как пере собрать массив что бы получить в таком виде

```
 Array
    (
        [ttn] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21256565225656363
            [1] => 456554654645356555
        )

        [phone] => Array
    (
        [0] => +380956173282
        [1] => +380956173282
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное так:

```
if(!empty($_POST['selected'])) {// тут приходят нужные id
    $result = array(
        'ttn' => array(),
        'phone' => array(),
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['selected']); $i++) {
        $order_id = $_POST['selected'][$i];
        $orders = $this->db->query("SELECT telephone, ttn FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'")->rows;

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $result['ttn'][] = $order['ttn'];
            $result['phone'][] = $order['telephone'];
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, то что надо.

Comment: @Sender1050 если ответ помог - отметьте его правильным. Слева от ответа галку поставьте